How to check if an attribute that belongs to multiple elements has one of several values
I'm trying to test whether an attribute that is shared by 3 elements has one of several values. Here's the html:

    <div class="wrapper">
      <a title="value 1"</a> 
      <a title="value 2"</a> 
      <a title="value 3"</a> 
    </div>


I need a way to assert that the title attribute of all three elements will have one of the 3 values, because their order might change in the future but I just need to make sure that they're there.
Here's what I've tried but didn't work for me:
cy.get('.wrapper')
    .children().as('socialLinks');

cy.get('@socialLinks')
    .should('have.attr', 'title').as('title');

expect('@title').to.contain.oneOf('value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3');

I suspect it might need a for-loop but I can't wrap my head around how to approach it.

A for-loop is possible but can cause problems in a Cypress test (search SO questions for some examples).
There is the .each() command which performs the for-loop in a Cypress-friendly way
cy.get('.wrapper').children()
  .each(($el) => {
    const title = $el.attr('title')
    expect(title).to.be.oneOf(['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3'])
  })

But if the values are loaded from an API, you should replace the expect() with a should() to make sure the test retries until loading is complete.
cy.get('.wrapper').children()
  .each(($el) => {
    cy.wrap($el).invoke('attr', 'title')
      .should('be.oneOf', ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3'])
  })


worked beautifully, thank you!

If you wanted to check if all 3 possible values are existent, no matter the order, AFAIS the simplest attempt would be just checking for existence:
cy.get('.wrapper a[title="value 1"]');
cy.get('.wrapper a[title="value 2"]');
cy.get('.wrapper a[title="value 3"]');

I never used cypress though and i´m not sure if thats actually what you are looking for.
